# Replacing the existing sheet in excel 2007 using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
Sub testmac()
'
' testmac Macro
'
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="items", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Report!R7C8:R486C11"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=path
        ), Array("P;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), Destination:= _
        Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "TRANSFORM first(`Dimension Value Code`)" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "SELECT items.`No#`, items.`Description`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM items" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "GROUP BY items.`No#`, items.`Description`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "PIVOT `Dimension Code`" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_Excel_FilesXY"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        End With

End Sub
```

I am trying to make a pivot table with this code. The first try went well as it had no sheets. When I tried for the second time it gave me an error as the sheet already existed with table in it having the same name as the previous one.

The error is

> Run-time error  '1004': Application-defined or object defined error

When I delete the worksheet created in the previous step and try running the macro again works properly, but it does not works without deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this at the top:

```
on error resume next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("your sheet").delete
on error goto 0
```

if it exists, it will be deleted and your code will make the new one. Does it help?

Comment: You may also want to sandwich that between `Application.DisplayAlerts = False/True` ;)